# Can I convert a Sloan valve with tank ?

Tags: toilet

I have a older toilet(1970’s) with Sloan valve flush system- can I replace the Sloan valve with a tank and keep the bowl?

Comment: Does the bowl have two holes for bolts for securing a tank directly to the bowl? As an alternative, there are tanks which mount high up on the wall and connect to the bowl with a pipe. This has the advantage of having a higher head pressure and so a stronger flush. Is the Sloan valve not working properly?

Comment: The bowl is designed to work with a certain volume and speed of flush. A low volume tank would probably not properly flush a bowl designed for a Sloan valve. New toilets probably do not cost much more than a replacement tank.

Comment: The bowl is a Crane and I don't see any Holes. there is nothing wrong with the Valve- [just the building management. Insisting it be replaced with tank ( we need To replace all the water risers- 1950 High rise. ]. I am looking for all options

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!